# Pandas no lee mi csv de manera correcta

Tags: python, pandas

Estoy intentando ocupar un csv, pero me detecta unicamente una columna, el csv pertenece a este link por si alguien puede ayudarme c_:
https://datos.bancomundial.org/indicador/EN.ATM.CO2E.KT?view=chart (Es el ultimo archivo del rar)

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv("EmisionesCO2.csv")

print(df.shape)
print(df.columns)
```

```
Salida: 
    (264, 1)
Index(['Country Name,Country Code,"Indicator Name","Indicator Code","1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1966","1967","1968","1969","1970","1971","1972","1973","1974","1975","1976","1977","1978","1979","1980","1981","1982","1983","1984","1985","1986","1987","1988","1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020",'], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Si revisas las primeras filas del `CSV`:

```
Data Source","Indicadores del desarrollo mundial",

"Last Updated Date","2020-12-16",

"Country Name","Country Code","Indicator Name","Indicator Code","1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1966","1967","1968","1969","1970","1971","1972","1973","1974","1975","1976","1977","1978","1979","1980","1981","1982","1983","1984","1985","1986","1987","1988","1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995","1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020",
"Aruba","ABW","Emisiones de CO2 (kt)","EN.ATM.CO2E.KT","11092.675","11576.719","12713.489","12178.107","11840.743","10623.299","9933.903","12236.779","11378.701","14891.687","16655.514","14495.651","14055.611","15592.084","14132.618","10234.597","21862.654","11419.038","9724.884","10201.594","10498.621","9999.909","11180.683","5746.189","14348.971","16794.86","179.683","447.374","612.389","649.059","487.711","531.715","539.049","649.059","660.06","707.731","726.066","759.069","806.74","810.407","2379.883","2409.219","2438.555","2563.233","2618.238","2720.914","2717.247","2823.59","2658.575","2629.239","2508.228","2500.894","1349.456","861.745","872.746","898.415","883.747","","","","",
"Afganistán","AFG","Emisiones de CO2 (kt)","EN.ATM.CO2E.KT","414.371","491.378","689.396","707.731","839.743","1008.425","1092.766","1283.45","1224.778","942.419","1672.152","1895.839","1532.806","1639.149","1917.841","2126.86","1987.514","2390.884","2159.863","2240.537","1760.16","1983.847","2101.191","2522.896","2830.924","3509.319","3142.619","3124.284","2867.594","2775.919","2614.571","2438.555","1393.46","1345.789","1294.451","1243.113","1177.107","1096.433","1041.428","821.408","773.737","817.741","1070.764","1213.777","916.75","1327.454","1650.15","2273.54","4206.049","6769.282","8463.436","12240.446","10755.311","9050.156","8467.103","9035.488","8672.455","","","","",
"Angola","AGO","Emisiones de CO2 (kt)","EN.ATM.CO2E.KT","550.05","454.708","1180.774","1151.438","1224.778","1188.108","1554.808","993.757","1672.152","2786.92","3582.659","3410.31","4506.743","4880.777","4873.443","4415.068","3285.632","3534.988","5412.492","5504.167","5346.486","5280.48","4649.756","5115.465","5009.122","4701.094","4660.757","5815.862","5130.133","5009.122","5115.465","5089.796","5196.139","5775.525","3890.687","10975.331","10458.284","7381.671","7308.331","9156.499","9541.534","9732.218","12665.818","9064.824","18793.375","19156.408","22266.024","25151.953","25709.337","27792.193","29057.308","30586.447","34176.44","33692.396","44851.077","34583.477","34693.487","","","","",
"Albania","ALB","Emisiones de CO2 (kt)","EN.ATM.CO2E.KT","2024.184","2280.874","2464.224","2082.856","2016.85","2174.531","2552.232","2680.577","3072.946","3245.295","3744.007","4352.729","5643.513","5291.481","4345.395","4594.751","4950.45","5720.52","6494.257","7587.023","5170.47","7341.334","7308.331","7631.027","7825.378","7880.383","8056.399","7444.01","7326.666","8984.15","5515.168","4286.723","2515.562","2335.879","1925.175","2086.523","2016.85","1543.807","1752.826","2984.938","3021.608","3223.293","3751.341","4294.057","4165.712","4253.72","3898.021","3927.357","4374.731","4378.398","4598.418","5240.143","4924.781","4913.78","5489.499","4616.753","4536.079","","","","",
```

---

Se puede notar que hay 4 filas que representan títulos, los datos recién comienzan en la 5 fila. Para solucionar esto, puedes usar el parámetro `skiprows` para ignorar un número determinado de filas al comienzo del archivo:

`df = pd.read_csv("EmisionesCO2.csv", sep=",", skiprows=4`)